# \begin{citacao} abntex top and bottom margin

Tags: spacing, templates, quoting

How can I remove the top and bottom margin of the `citacao` item in `abntex`? It currently looks like this image:
[image]

I need it to have just a single space between lines.

The `abntex` implementation is

```
\newenvironment{citado}%
  {\begin{espacosimples}%
   \small
   \begin{list}{}{%
       \setlength{\listparindent}{0cm}%
       \setlength{\itemindent}{\listparindent}%
       \setlength{\rightmargin}{0cm}%
       \setlength{\leftmargin}{4cm}%
       \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}}%
    \item\relax}%
  {\end{list}\end{espacosimples}}

\newenvironment{citacao}%
  {\begin{citado}}%
  {\end{citado}}%
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). For inline code, you can use backticks `\``.

Comment: Does `\AtBeginEnvironment{citado}{\partopsep=0pt \parskip=0pt}` help?

Comment: Unless I did someting wrong, it didn`t work!
@PauloCereda I added \vspace{-5 mm} might not be the right way, but at least it worked :)